# Looping through instances and changing value of specific instance parameter goes wrong

Tags: python, loops

I am currently going through one of online beginner courses for Python3 where a guy makes an RPG games in order to show its functionalities.

So in general the game works in main.py and uses 3 classes, each in separate file. Classes are Person, Spell and Item

Basically it works in a loop for whole game, and inside of it, it loops through each player in party (3 players, one enemy).

Person class looks lihe this:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, hp, mp, atk, df, magic, items):
        self.maxhp = hp
        self.hp = hp
        self.maxmp = mp
        self.mp = mp
        self.atkl = atk - 15
        self.atkh = atk + 15
        self.df = df
        self.magic = magic
        self.items = items
        self.actions = ["Attack", "Magic", "Items"]
        self.name = name
```

Now straight to the problem:

When i pass dictionary/array with items using one variable this way:

```
player_items = [{"item": potion, "quantity": 4}, 
                {"item": superPotion, "quantity": 5},
                {"item": elixer, "quantity": 5},
                {"item": grenade, "quantity": 2}]

player1 = Person("Nasteroth", 460, 130, 65, 34, player_spells, player_items)
player2 = Person("Vidala   ", 380, 200, 55, 34, player_spells, player_items)
player3 = Person("Xerogas  ", 540, 100, 80, 34, player_spells, player_items)
```

and then, during player1 turn when it should reduce the quantity of used item by 1 for player1 only, it reduces the quantity for ALL players which we are looping through?

Part of loop here:

```
players = [player1, player2, player3]

for player in players:

    item_choice = int(input(BColors.OKGREEN + "Choose item to use: " + BColors.ENDC)) - 1

    item = player.items[item_choice]

    if item["item"].type == "potion":
        player.heal(item["item"].prop)
        print(BColors.OKGREEN, "\n", item["item"].name, "heals for", str(item["item"].prop), "HP", BColors.ENDC)
        item["quantity"] -= 1
```

But when i pass items the manual way:

```
player1 = Person("Nasteroth", 460, 130, 65, 34, player_spells, [{"item": potion, "quantity": 4}, {"item": superPotion, "quantity": 5},
                {"item": elixer, "quantity": 5},
                {"item": grenade, "quantity": 2}])
player2 = Person("Vidala   ", 380, 200, 55, 34, player_spells, [{"item": potion, "quantity": 4}, {"item": superPotion, "quantity": 5},
                {"item": elixer, "quantity": 5},
                {"item": grenade, "quantity": 2}])
player3 = Person("Xerogas  ", 540, 100, 80, 34, player_spells, [{"item": potion, "quantity": 4}, {"item": superPotion, "quantity": 5},
                {"item": elixer, "quantity": 5},
                {"item": grenade, "quantity": 2}])
```

The code works fine and it reduces the quantity of used item for each player separately.

Is there something with Python3 which i dont know yet about some global parameters or something?

EDIT:

Pasting more code would make it a wall of text so the full code can be found here:
https://pastebin.com/4V6NFu1z

Comment: ALL your players have the same single backpack of items `player_items`. Show your `Person` class.

Comment: Put it into the question, not into comments where the code is unreadable.

Comment: Is it your full code? Are you sure it is working? There are a lot of issues which make it invalid.

Comment: added a link with full code at bottom of my question, all files are included along with all classes.
Generally the code is okay it launches and does what its supposed to do except items.
Whole program is still work in progess so some functionalities were not added yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplify your code (turning some data to strings in player_items), to make it work. In any case, it illustrates the idea. Launch:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, hp, mp, atk, df, magic, items):
        self.maxhp = hp
        self.hp = hp
        self.maxmp = mp
        self.mp = mp
        self.atkl = atk - 15
        self.atkh = atk + 15
        self.df = df
        self.magic = magic
        self.items = items
        self.actions = ["Attack", "Magic", "Items"]
        self.name = name


player_spells = None

player_items = [{"item": "potion", "quantity": 4}, 
                {"item": "superPotion", "quantity": 5},
                {"item": "elixer", "quantity": 5},
                {"item": "grenade", "quantity": 2}]

player1 = Person("Nasteroth", 460, 130, 65, 34, player_spells, player_items)
player2 = Person("Vidala   ", 380, 200, 55, 34, player_spells, player_items)
# 1
print(id(player1.items))
print(id(player2.items))
# 2
print((player1.items))
print((player2.items))

player1.items[0] = {}
# 3
print((player1.items))
print((player2.items))
```

It will show you that 1) both players have same items, but 2) ID of these objects are the same: both players hold same references, so manipulate the same data in the memory, which is shown in print 3): change to one player's data, changes the other player's items.

If you introduce a small change in the above code (note the `.copy()`) and say:

```
player2 = Person("Vidala   ", 380, 200, 55, 34, player_spells, player_items.copy())
```

Then, the two players will have two different `items` lists, and manipulating one, won't update the other. Also, the `id`s of objects will be different.

Comment: Happy to hear that. Can you accept my answer, then?